# Test Class no getting even 1% coverage

Tags: lead-conversion, future, before-trigger

I have the following code I found here: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000093JmIAI

```java
trigger Lead on Lead (before insert, before update) {       
    if (Trigger.isBefore) {
        if (Trigger.isUpdate){ 

            Set<Id> setLeadIds = new Set<Id>();  
            Set<Id> setConvertedOppIds = new Set<Id>();  

            for (Lead ld : Trigger.new) {

                // Find all converted Leads with Opportunitiy and add ConvertedOpportunityId to setConvertedOppIds
                if (ld.isConverted && ld.ConvertedOpportunityId != null 
                    && Trigger.oldMap.get(ld.Id).ConvertedOpportunityId != ld.ConvertedOpportunityId){
                    setConvertedOppIds.add(ld.ConvertedOpportunityId);          
            }       

            if (!Statics.inFutureContext) {
                if (!setConvertedOppIds.isEmpty()){
                    OpportunityTeamProcessor.createOpportunityTeamMember(setConvertedOppIds);
                }
            }
        }       
    }   
}
```

and this is the test Class I did for it:

```java
@isTest
private class LeadTrigger_Test{
    static testMethod void test_LeadTrigger(){
        test.startTest();
        Lead lead_Obj = new Lead(LastName = 'LastName284', Company = 'Company396', Status = 'Unqualified', IsConverted = false, IsUnreadByOwner = false, Analyzed_Account_in_details_in_Rogers_SF__c = false, Verified_if_Lead_is_an_existing_customer__c = false, Serviceability__c = false);
        Insert lead_Obj; 
       test.stopTest();
    }

    static testMethod void test_UseCase1(){
        test.startTest();
        Lead lead_Obj = new Lead(LastName = 'LastName284', Company = 'Company396', Status = 'Unqualified', IsConverted = false, IsUnreadByOwner = false, Analyzed_Account_in_details_in_Rogers_SF__c = false, Verified_if_Lead_is_an_existing_customer__c = false, Serviceability__c = false);
        lead_Obj.LastName='UseCase2-1';
        lead_Obj.Company='UseCase2-1';
        lead_Obj.Status='UseCase2-1';
        lead_Obj.IsConverted=false;
        lead_Obj.IsUnreadByOwner=false;
        lead_Obj.Analyzed_Account_in_details_in_Rogers_SF__c=false;
        lead_Obj.Verified_if_Lead_is_an_existing_customer__c=false;
        lead_Obj.Serviceability__c=false;
        Insert lead_Obj; 
        test.stopTest();
    }

    static testMethod void test_UseCase2(){
        test.startTest();
        Lead lead_Obj = new Lead(LastName = 'LastName284', Company = 'Company396', Status = 'Unqualified', IsConverted = false, IsUnreadByOwner = false, Analyzed_Account_in_details_in_Rogers_SF__c = false, Verified_if_Lead_is_an_existing_customer__c = false, Serviceability__c = false);
        lead_Obj.LastName='UseCase2-1';
        lead_Obj.Company='UseCase2-1';
        lead_Obj.Status='UseCase2-1';
        lead_Obj.IsConverted=true;
        lead_Obj.IsUnreadByOwner=false;
        lead_Obj.Analyzed_Account_in_details_in_Rogers_SF__c=false;
        lead_Obj.Verified_if_Lead_is_an_existing_customer__c=false;
        lead_Obj.Serviceability__c=false;
        lead_Obj.LastName='UseCase1-0';
        lead_Obj.Company='UseCase1-0';
        lead_Obj.Status='UseCase1-0';
        lead_Obj.IsConverted=false;
        lead_Obj.IsUnreadByOwner=false;
        lead_Obj.Analyzed_Account_in_details_in_Rogers_SF__c=false;
        lead_Obj.Verified_if_Lead_is_an_existing_customer__c=false;
        lead_Obj.Serviceability__c=false;
        Insert lead_Obj; 
        test.stopTest();
    }

    static testMethod void test_UseCase3(){
        test.startTest();
        Lead lead_Obj = new Lead(LastName = 'LastName284', Company = 'Company396', Status = 'Unqualified', IsConverted = false, IsUnreadByOwner = false, Analyzed_Account_in_details_in_Rogers_SF__c = false, Verified_if_Lead_is_an_existing_customer__c = false, Serviceability__c = false);
        lead_Obj.isConverted =false;
        test.stopTest();
    }   
}
```

But I can't get a 1% coverage when deployed to production from SandBox, can a guru here help me with this and let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Questions on code coverage are pretty common here, so don't be too surprised if your question here gets closed eventually. It's getting late where I am, so I'm not going to write up an answer now. But, I will give you some quick advice. The fundamental rule of unit testing is **you only gain coverage for code that's executed as part of a test method**.  All of the code in the trigger that you copied only does work in a `before update` context (looks like it should be `after update` to me, but that's another matter). Do you ever update a `Lead` in your test methods?

Comment: Doh you at least get the first two lines covered?

Comment: Also make sure your trigger is active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For proper testing, you must actually convert the lead using the LeadConvert class:

```
@isTest static void test() {
    Lead testLead = new Lead(...);
    insert testLead;
    Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
    lc.setLeadId(testLead.Id);
    lc.setConvertedStatus('Qualified');
    Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
    // Important--make sure your test passes
    System.assertEquals(1,
        [SELECT COUNT() FROM OpportunityTeamMember],
        'Expected a new opportunity team member');
}
```

Since your code never got to the point of converting the lead, you'd only cover 1 line of code anyways. While that might technically get you to 1%, you've made no attempt to actually get proper code coverage, despite the small amount of effort you'd need to get there. Taking shortcuts like this will most likely lead to problems in the future. You should get used to writing proper unit tests instead of trying to get only just enough coverage to scrape by.